# Java Using Strings as Code

Tags: java

Okay, so, here's what I have in code:

```
public void makeObject(int i){
    String s = getString(i); //This returns the name of a class
    new s(); //This is what I want to do
}
```

Can I do this?

Comment: Do you just want to create a new instance of an already-existing class? Then look at [Class.forName](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) which will return a Class.

Comment: Better suited to StackOverflow?

Comment: Why are you doing this?  For sending messages across a network?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No you can't do this, but what you're probably looking for is called 'reflection'.

Look at these series of (free) slides: http://www.slideshare.net/CiaranMcHale/java-reflection-explained-simply especially slide 11, but read the ones before that as well. It will give you an idea of what reflection is and a way to make a class by knowing the name (as a string) and how to instantiate a new instance of that class.

You can also find methods and fields by name, you can even modify existing classes in code.

Edit: for example the following code will return a class by string name

```
Class cls = Class.ForName("MyPackage.MyClassName");
return cls.NewInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks, haven't looked at it yet, but I think it is perfect by how you described it.